# Validating Geo-Coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

How do I validate a given `coordinates` ?

```
latitude = "-70.578444";
longitude = "-11.987444";
```

the above coordinates are invalid. However, using my logic provided below it still passes through. How can I solve this ?

I tried the following: But it passes through:

```
if ( (latitude >-90.0 && latitude < 90.0) && (longitude >-180.0 && longitude < 180.0) ) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have function isCoordinatesValid with return type of `bool`.
One coordinate must be checked is it bigger than some value. I guess that the latitude can't be smaller than -90 and bigger than 90. Same for longitude(180). I hope this is the right logic.

```
if(latitude < -90.0 || latitude > 90.0) {
return false;
}

else if (longitude <-180.0 || longitude >180.0) {
return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: However, my coordinates return true. It should return false. How can I correct this ?

Comment: @Illep Why should it return false? Your coordinates fit within those ranges.